# Using CSS To Style Posts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a feed of posts for my bloglike application. I'm trying to arrange it so posts are grouped by month and there are 3 posts displayed per line.

This is my code for my feed partial:

```
<% @posts_by_month.each do |monthname, posts| %>

<%= monthname %>

   <% posts.each do |post| %>
     <div style="width:100%">
     <div style="float:left;width:33%"><%= post.created_at %></div>
     </div>
   <% end %>

<% end %>
```

& this is the @posts_by_month in my controller:

```
@posts_by_month = current_user.feed.group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B") }
```

This currently styles it like in this screenshot:
[image]

When the code reaches a new month I want the month to be on a new line like the arrow demonstrates, rather than part of the same block like it is currently. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the month name in:

```
<div style="clear:left"><%= monthname %></div>
```

This will make the `monthname` 'clear' anything that is floated left.

You could make it easier on yourself though by using a grid system or using flexbox like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNZqaM.

You shouldn't have to use floats for this purpose

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to figure this out for hours & this one line fixed it :)

Comment: I would definitely recommend that you look into bootstrap or zurbfoundation to make your html/css life easier. Using divs like this is a recipe for a good headache.